# Multiple array combine

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I have a working update, from a multiple entry:

```
foreach(array_combine($_POST['eprof'] , $_POST['estudno']) as $prof => $sn){
    mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE  `table` SET  `studno` =  '$sn' WHERE  `students`.`id` = '$prof'") or die(mysqli_error());                                    
}
foreach(array_combine($_POST['eprof'] , $_POST['efn']) as $prof => $f){
    mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE  `table` SET  `fn` = '$f' WHERE  `students`.`id` = '$prof'") or die(mysqli_error());
}
foreach(array_combine($_POST['eprof'] , $_POST['emn']) as $prof => $m){
    mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE  `table` SET  `mn` ='$m' WHERE  `students`.`id` = '$prof'") or die(mysqli_error());
}
```

The code above is from selected student/s one or many depending on the checkbox checked. Is there a way to do this with a cleaner `foreach`, like combining `$sn`, `$fn`, `$m` in one?

```
foreach(
    array_combine(
      $_POST['eprof'] ,
      $_POST['estudno'],
      $_POST['efn'],
      $_POST['emn']
    ) as 
   $prof => $sn => $f => $m
){ "query here" }
```

Is this correct or I'm doing it wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that they are identically keyed:

```
foreach($_POST['eprof'] as $key => $prof){
    $sn = $_POST['estudno'][$key];
    $f  = $_POST['efn'][$key];
    $m  = $_POST['emn'][$key];

    mysqli_query($con, "UPDATE `table` SET `studno` =  '$sn', `fn` = '$f', `mn` ='$m'   
                        WHERE  `students`.`id` = '$prof'");
}
```

If not identically keyed then you can run `array_values()` on the 3 arrays first to re-index.

Comment: identically keyed meaning , same number of arrays ?

Comment: Yes, same number of elements with the array keys match.

Comment: yes they are, thanks.. as the code above was from my previous which was too long and redundant on $prof